# SQL - How do I filter results with keyword out of normal order and place them at bottom?

Tags: php, sql, ms-access, odbc

I have a website I am rebuilding with PHP to read from an Access database. I have most of the functionality for displaying lists of products based on what category from a dropdown is selected. However, one thing I'd like to do is move all the obsolete products to the bottom of the results list. Currently, they are mixed within the displayed results.

Is there a SQL statement that will allow me to do this? Currently, all the obsolete products in the database have "(Obsolete)" appended at the end of their product name. I'm hoping I can target the string (Obsolete) to do this.

Here is my current SQL statement:

```
$handle = odbc_connect("Potter","","");
$results = odbc_exec($handle, "SELECT DISTINCT product.prodimage, 
                product.prodmodelno, 
                product.proddesc, 
                product.prodorder, 
                product.prodpdf, 
                product.prodmanual, 
                product.prodtip 
FROM   product 
WHERE  (( ( product.prodmodelno ) LIKE '%$searchTerm%' )) 
        OR (( ( product.proddesc ) LIKE '%$searchTerm%' )) 
ORDER  BY product.prodorder DESC, 
          product.prodmodelno ASC ");
```

Comment: What you should have is a column in the product table called `obsolete` that you can then sort on.

Comment: Good idea. I added a prodObs column to the database with a default value of 0. For all products that ARE obsolete, the value = 1. I then placed a SORT BY of prodObs, then prodOrder, then prodModelNo.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `ORDER` using a `IIF` statement (which is like a `CASE` in ANSI SQL)

http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php

So you might sort by (untested):

`IIF (RIGHT(product.[proddesc],10) = "(Obsolete)", "b", "a")`

This creates a new derived column, which is "b" when obsolete and "a" otherwise....